# How to use bootstrap dropdown in creation forms?

Tags: forms, twitter-bootstrap

I don't know how I can satisfy connection with database.

Now I have this code in my _form:

```
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.select :language, options_for_select(%w[English Chinese Ukrainian]) %>
  </div>
```

How I can do it with bootstrap or how I can make it look like bootstrap ?